# Want to redirect to the URL after successfully submitting the form JS

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect

Want to redirect to the URL after successfully submitting the form JS.
Here is my code. I have 2 different forms, and I need to redirect them to another URL. Want to redirect to the URL after successfully submitting the form JS.
Here is my code. I have 2 different forms, and I need to redirect them to another URL. Want to redirect to the URL after successfully submitting the form JS.
Here is my code. I have 2 different forms, and I need to redirect them to another URL.

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        var form = $('#ajaxContact');
        var formMessages = $('#contactMessage');
        $(form).submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (jQuery(".email", this).val() == '' && jQuery(".message", this).val() == '' && jQuery(".name", this).val() == '') {
                $(formMessages).text('Required fields must be filled');
                return false;
            }
            var formData = $(form).serialize();
            formData += '&subjects=New Contact Us Message&phone="None"&required=email,name,message';
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: $(form).attr('action'),
                    data: formData
                })
                .done(function(response) {
                    $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
                    $(formMessages).addClass('success');
                    // Set the message text.
                    $(formMessages).text(response);
                    jQuery(".email", this).val('');
                    jQuery(".name", this).val('');
                    jQuery(".message", this).val('');
                })
                .fail(function(data) {
                    // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
                    $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
                    $(formMessages).addClass('errors');
                    // Set the message text.
                    if (data.responseText !== '') {
                        $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
                    } else {
                        $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
                    }
                });
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        var form = $('#callMe');
        var formMessages = $('#callMeMessage');
        $(form).submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (jQuery(".email", this).val() == '' && jQuery(".phone", this).val() == '') {
                $(formMessages).text('One of the filds must be filled');
                return false;
            }
            var formData = $(form).serialize();
            formData += '&name=Call Me Service&subjects=New "Call Me" request from Webzool site function&message=No Message&required=subjects,name';
            console.log(formData);
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: $(form).attr('action'),
                    data: formData
                })
                .done(function(response) {
                    $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
                    $(formMessages).addClass('success');
                    // Set the message text.
                    $(formMessages).text(response);
                    jQuery(".email", this).val('');
                    jQuery(".phone", this).val('');
                })
                .fail(function(data) {
                    // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
                    $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
                    $(formMessages).addClass('errors');
                    // Set the message text.
                    if (data.responseText !== '') {
                        $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
                    } else {
                        $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
                    }
                });
        });
    });
```

I would be very happy if you can help. Thanks

Comment: try `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");` within the `done` state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `.done` function you can add :`window.location.href = 'webURL';`
or `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");`

This will ensure that it will only redirect if the ajax call has been successful.

Example with your code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: $(form).attr('action'),
  data: formData
})
.done(function(response) {
  $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
  $(formMessages).addClass('success');
  // Set the message text.
  $(formMessages).text(response);
  jQuery(".email", this).val('');
  jQuery(".phone", this).val('');
  window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.done(function(response) {

      window.open('<Redirection url>','_self');

}
```

Comment: You can significantly improve the quality of this answer by explaining what and how it does.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get successful response you can use the following line to redirect to your desired location.

```
window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";// the URL where you want to redirect your user
```